# Why are my layers after sharing and re-downloading a QGIS map almost all unavailable?

Tags: qgis, layers, data-source

I have made a map on QGIS and when I save it and send it to myself and re-open it, the layers are unavailable. The only layer that shows up is the one I got through ArcGIS Feature Layer service. It says it can't find the data source for all the other layers.

The way I made the layers that are now unavailable was by adding a shapefile. I then filtered the shapefile and exported it as a new layer and added it to the map.

Comment: QGIS Geopackage layers (for sharing) https://freegistutorial.com/how-to-create-a-geopackage-on-qgis-3-2/ (has a video)

Comment: Did you use relative path ?

Comment: @Babel - that's an answer not a comment, if you move it people can vote for it

Answer (score 7):

QGIS does **NOT** save the data (layers) in QGIS-project files. You **always** need to have access to the files/databases that store the layer-data when you open a QGIS project.

QGIS uses relative or absolute paths for referring to these files, so if you move your data or the QGIS project to another folder, QGIS might not find them and you must manually set the path again.

So if you want to send someone a QGIS-project, always add all the layer-data and make sure to have a folder-structure that makes them accessible: easiest is to store the project and all data in the same folder.

An option would be to store all together in one single zip-compressed file. Another similar option is to save project + data files to the same Geopackage. However, depending on context (operating system, QGIS version etc.) this might not work properly.

Answer (score 6):

The best way, I guess, to get rid of this kind of error is to save the source files in the same folder that contains the project file and to set "Save paths" option to "Relative" in "Project Properties -> General" tab.